# How can I redirect users to different pages based on former sessions in Flask?

Tags: flask

I'm creating a website in Flask and I would like to redirect new users to a different page than users who have already visited my website.

Answer (score 0):

Just return `redirect(some_url)` in your @app.route

for the requested url, i did not understand well your needs

Where do you want the new user to be redirected exactly ?